# jQuery add class then toggle both class

Tags: javascript, jquery

when first click on the button I need to add the class `.valid_tick` to the div `#valid_div`.

after any click it should toggle class 
like this `$('#valid_div').toggleClass('invalid_tick');`

right now I'm suding like this which shows both class at a time :( 
present code

```
$(".validation_hide").slideToggle();
$('#valid_div').toggleClass('invalid_tick');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
$('#valid_div').click(function() {
    $div = $(this);
    if ($div.hasClass('valid_tick')) {
        $div.toggleClass('invalid_tick');
    } else {
        $div.addClass('valid_tick');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to do this:

Set 'invalid_tick' class to the #valid_div object from the beginning:

```
<div id='valid_div' class='invalid_tick'> .... </div>
```

js

```
$('#valid_div').click(function() {
    $div = $(this);
    $div.toggleClass('valid_tick');
    $div.toggleClass('invalid_tick');
});
```

If you can't have the 'invalid_tick' from the start, I would go for:

```
$('#valid_div').click(function() {
    $div = $(this);
    if (!$div.hasClass('valid_tick')) {
        $div.addClass('valid_tick');
    }
    else {
        $div.toggleClass('valid_tick');
        $div.toggleClass('invalid_tick');
    }
});
```